# Replace head of a file with the contents of another file

Tags: python

I have two files:

File A:

```
line A_1
line A_2
line A_3
...
line A_n
```

File B:

```
line B_1
line B_2
...
line B_n
line B_n+1
...
line B_m
```

I want the first `n` lines of file A to replace the first `n` lines of file B (`m > n`). After this file B should look like this:

File B:

```
line A_1
...
line A_n
line B_n+1
...
line B_m
```

What is the most pythonic solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open("newB.txt","wb") as fout:
    with open("B.txt") as b:
        for lineA,lineB in zip(open("A.txt"),b):
            fout.write(lineA)
        fout.writelines(b)
```

maybe ... I guess...

Comment: of coarse you can ... (you might have to append a `"\n"` to the `fout.write(lineA)` bit ...)

Comment: on my little test case the zip(...) returns an empty list... []

Comment: ok I fixed that - bad test case. But now I'm getting this error: "ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data" on the last line of your snippet.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(A) as fp_A:
    for i, line in enumerate(fp_A):
        if i <= n:
            print(line)
        else:
            break
with open(B) as fp_B:
    for i, line in enumerate(fp_B):
        if i > n:
            print(line)
```